# QLPreviewController detect when QLPreviewItem Changed

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I have application that use QLPreviewController to show document from MS. Office. I use this controller to multiple files. I need to log which files that already viewed. But I can't find event that triggered when PreviewItem changed.

I try to trigger event when GetPreviewItem called, But this method just called 1 time each preview item. So I can't use this.

Anyone can help me to find how to detect QLPreviewItem changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift). Subclass the `QLPreviewController` and add something like this:

```
var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    observation = observe(\.currentPreviewItemIndex, options: [.new] ) { _, change in
        // You get the new index value in change.newValue
    }
}
```